# Catching "close" socket event in node.js

Tags: apache, node.js, sockets, mod-proxy

I'm using the Apache on port 80.

Node.js server listen on port 1337, Apache through him all proxied requests:

```
ProxyRequests off

ProxyPass /nodejs/ http://127.0.0.1:1337/ timeout=300 retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /nodejs/ http://127.0.0.1:1337/
```

And server.js:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    req.socket.on("close", function () {
        console.log("socket close");
    });
}).listen(1337);
```

Problem: When the connection aborted by the user (stop request in browser, for example pressing Esc), node.js can't fire *socket.on("close")* till apache's timeout is alive.

What are the solutions to the problem, other than put Apache behind node.js?

Comment: Shorten timeout on Apache? Use nginx? Don't use any proxy at all?

Comment: Need a big timeout (otherwise, the meaning is lost long polling). No, but I looking for Apache's possible solutions. I really need a proxy (port 80 listen Apache).